# 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to write a so-called "Facharbeit", in which I chose to solve a difficult question of a test(about which I probably have to ask questions later).
So, I first had to summon a tkinter window and I added a Label like this:

```
b = tkinter.Label(GUI,"Facharbeit:Bundeswettbewerbsaufgabe")
b.place(GUI,"top")
``
line 16, b = tkinter.Label(GUI,"Facharbeit:Bundeswettbewerbsaufgabe")
  File "C:\Users\rebec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3148, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\rebec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2569, in __init__
    classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

So, I made an error in this line:

```
b = tkinter.Label(GUI,"Facharbeit:Bundeswettbewerbsaufgabe")
```

But I can't see any errors there, can anyone help me?

Comment: Get familiar with reading [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#label-options) - You need to use keyword when passing options to a tkinter widget, in this case `text` for the Label

Comment: @Mandera you don't *need* to do `text=` but yes documentation is a good habit

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to write the alternative right away instead of only nitpicking? :)

Comment: @Mandera i wrote the alternative in the answer, thought you'd look there if necessary, sorry; it's `{"text": ...}` as the 2nd arg

Answer (score 3):

`tkinter.Label`'s signature is:

```py
tkinter.Label(master=None, cnf={}, **kw)
```

what you did is:

```py
tkinter.Label(GUI, "Facharbeit:Bundeswettbewerbsaufgabe")
```

Since you passed both arguments positionally, `GUI` corresponds to `master` (fine) and `"Fachar..."` does to `cnf` (short for configuration) - not fine. In fact, you passed a string to what expects a dictionary, and it attempted to get `.items()` of it, hence the error.

Either do:

```py
tkinter.Label(GUI, {"text": "Facharbeit:Bundeswettbewerbsaufgabe"})
```

or

```py
tkinter.Label(GUI, text="Facharbeit:Bundeswettbewerbsaufgabe")
```

where this latter option is thanks to that `**kw` part; documentation states what options you can pass there as a keyword argument:

```
STANDARD OPTIONS

    activebackground, activeforeground, anchor,
    background, bitmap, borderwidth, cursor,
    disabledforeground, font, foreground,
    highlightbackground, highlightcolor,
    highlightthickness, image, justify,
    padx, pady, relief, takefocus, text,      <-- text here!
    textvariable, underline, wraplength
```